# Sets of points in $x-y$ plane

Tags: elementary-set-theory, coordinate-systems

I need help with the following problem: Sketch the set of points in the $x-y$ plane $$\{(x,x+y): x\in\Bbb R,\ y\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

What would be the best way to approach this type of problem? I tried picking some numbers and putting those points into the plane but that doesn't seem wise. These are for instance some of the points: $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (2,-2), (\pi, \pi)...$

Comment: They are parallel lines with integer-height differences.

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, I saw that in the solution manual. They are parallel lines with the slope of $1$, right? How did you figure that out?

Comment: Observe $(x, x+n)= (x, x)+(0, n)$, i.e. shift your diagonal up and down by integer $n$.

Comment: Does anyone know how to plot this on desmos?

Answer (score 0):

If you plot this , you should get a set of horizontal parallel lines . To be exact , you will get the lines ... y=-2x , y=-x , y=0 , y=x ,y=2x ... and so on. 
To get an idea about this problem let x be a real number and y be a natural number. Then you will get a set of verticle parallel lines.

Comment: No, you're wrong.